# перебор ключей словаря в случайном порядке без повторений

Tags: python, python-3.x, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть ли возможность перебрать рандомно ключи словаря без повторений?

У меня есть словарь с английскими словами и их переводом на русский, т.е 1 ключ: 1 значение. Надо их каждый раз, при запуске программы выводить рандомно эти ключи, но без повторения

Пробовал применить метод shuffle из random но вылезает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ключи словаря уникальны по определению!

Comment: @MaxU В том то и дело, что у меня ключи всегда при выводе на одном и том же находятся, хотя всегда казалось раньше что они рандомно выводятся

Comment: я говорил не о порядке, в котором они выводятся, а о самих ключах.  Вы можете привести пример (в вопросе) входного словаря и несколько вариантов того, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU все просто, у меня есть словарь с английскими словами и их переводом на русский, т.е 1 ключ: 1 значение. Надо их каждый раз, при запуске программы выводить рандомно эти ключи, но без повторения

Comment: не используйте картинки для текста ошибок (это затрудняет поиск ответов для людей с похожей проблемой). Скопируйте как текст из консоли в вопрос и отформатируйте как код (Ctrl + K).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример:

```
import random

d = {
  'one':'один',
  'two':'два',
  'three':'три',
  'four':'четыре',
  'five':'пять'
}

In [39]: random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))
Out[39]: ['one', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'five']

In [40]: random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))
Out[40]: ['five', 'three', 'one', 'four', 'two']

In [41]: random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))
Out[41]: ['one', 'three', 'two', 'four', 'five']

In [42]: random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))
Out[42]: ['two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three']
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

In [64]: OrderedDict([(k,d[k]) for k in random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))])
Out[64]:
OrderedDict([('two', 'два'),
             ('one', 'один'),
             ('three', 'три'),
             ('five', 'пять'),
             ('four', 'четыре')])

In [65]: OrderedDict([(k,d[k]) for k in random.sample(d.keys(), len(d))])
Out[65]:
OrderedDict([('five', 'пять'),
             ('three', 'три'),
             ('four', 'четыре'),
             ('one', 'один'),
             ('two', 'два')])
```

или:

```
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

def shuffle_dict(d):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    return OrderedDict([(k, d[k]) for k in keys])
```

Использование:

```
In [89]: shuffle_dict(d)
Out[89]:
OrderedDict([('three', 'три'),
             ('four', 'четыре'),
             ('five', 'пять'),
             ('one', 'один'),
             ('two', 'два')])

In [90]: shuffle_dict(d)
Out[90]:
OrderedDict([('one', 'один'),
             ('three', 'три'),
             ('two', 'два'),
             ('five', 'пять'),
             ('four', 'четыре')])

In [91]: shuffle_dict(d)
Out[91]:
OrderedDict([('three', 'три'),
             ('four', 'четыре'),
             ('two', 'два'),
             ('one', 'один'),
             ('five', 'пять')])
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, правда странно что нет метода возвращающего именно словарь исходный а не новый лист. Видимо это связано с проблемой реализации ?

Comment: @helsereet, порядок ключей в словаре не гарантирован, так что перемешать словарь нельзя. Только отдельно ключи.

Comment: @helsereet, для этого можно использовать `collections.OrderedDict` - смотрите UPDATE

Answer (score 7):

Словарь — это неупорядоченная структура данных в Питоне (до Python 3.7). Порядок обхода может поменяться даже внутри одного и того же процесса (для разных словарей или для одного и того же словаря при вставке/удалении ключей). С другой стороны, в зависимости от реализации и настроек порядок ключей может повторяться и между запусками программы (в CPython 3.6 *реализации* словарь вообще упорядоченным является).

Можно *отдельный список ключей использовать и вручную его перемешать*, чтобы не полагаться на [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) и другие особенности реализации словарей:

```
import random

keys = list(your_dict)
random.shuffle(keys)
```

Если хотите использовать словарь, который гарантированно сохраняет порядок вставки ключей:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

your_dict = OrderedDict(zip(keys, map(your_dict.get, keys)))
```

Просто для обхода ключей не нужно OrderedDict создавать.